# Testing the same condition without OR operator

Tags: c

My lecturer does not want us to use the OR operator when using an if statement neither should both condition testing be on the same line.
eg.

```
if(condition1 || condition2){
  statement
}
if(condition1 || condition3){
  statement
}
```

But we've received a project asking for us to update books where the user can select either options, or both options. I tried using a switch, but I think its too long.

A sample of the code is below. However, is there any way to shorten it without using the `case 3` and typing redundant code.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int opt;

    printf("(1) Option 1");
    printf("\n(2) Option 2");
    printf("\n(3) Both\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf(" %d", &opt);
    switch(opt){
        case 1:
            printf("\nThis is option one");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nThis is option two");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nThis is option one");
            printf("\nThis is option two");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use tags for irrelevant languages. If this is about `c`, then `javascript`, `java` or `c++` have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: *"My lecturer does not want us to use the OR operator"* Then what does he want you to use? These kind of theoretical questions are hard to answer, because real life coding doesn't have such arbitrary restrictions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to avoid the OR. The relevant one

```
not (A or B) = not A and not B
```

which when transformed to your case becomes

```
A or B = not (not A and not B)
```

Here is the truth table to showcase this logic

| A | B | A or B | not A | not B | not A and not B | not(not A and not B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | true | false | false | false | true |
| true | false | true | false | true | false | true |
| false | true | true | true | false | false | true |
| false | false | false | true | true | true | false |

So with this in mind the condition

```
if(condition1 || condition2)
```

turns into

```
if (! (!condition1 && !condition2) )
```

Comment: This being the accepted answer raises issues with the question itself and the conditions it imposes.  Writing `if (! (!condition1 && !condition2) )` because of some arbitrary and foolish prohibition on a simple and readable `if(condition1 || condition2)` means the code is much harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't disagree. Still, sometimes you *do* have to do that. Let's say you're designing a logic circuit and you have AND gates but no OR gates. So in that case, you might have to complicate the logic for the system. I don't know what OP's lecturer's goal is here - maybe it *was* to exercise De Morgan's (boolean logic), maybe it was for bitwise operations (binary computation). Maybe it was to throw a curveball and see how it's resolved. Maybe it was simply bad. I think De Morgan's laws are good to know but I also don't think I'd ever apply them like this in real world code.

Answer (score 7):

In this case you can use the bitwise AND-operator (&) instead:

```
if(opt & 1)
{
  // option 1 or 3 chosen
}
if(opt & 2)
{
  // option 2 or 3 chosen
}
```

The decimal numbers `1`, `2` and `3` are in binary `01`, `10` and `11` respectively. (Denoted as `0b01`, `0b10` and `0b11` below to distinguish from decimal numbers).

The *bitwise AND-operator* yields a `1` if and only if both bits are `1`.
I.e. `1 & 1 = 1`, `0 & 1 = 0`, `1 & 0 = 0` and `0 & 0 = 0`.

Truth-table:

```
&   0  1
   -----
0 | 0  0
1 | 0  1
```

When `opt` equals 1 then only the first if-statement is true.
`0b01 & 0b01 = 0b01` (**true**) and `0b01 & 0b10 = 0b00` (**false**)

When `opt` equals 2 then only the second if-statement is true.
`0b10 & 0b01 = 0b00` (**false**) and `0b10 & 0b10 = 0b10` (**true**)

When `opt` equals 3 then both if-statements are true.
`0b11 & 0b01 = 0b01` (**true**) and `0b11 & 0b10 = 0b10` (**true**)

Anything not zero is true so all your conditions are met accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

1 is `0b01`, 2 is `0b10` and 3 is `0b11`.

Therefore use the idiomatic

```
if (opt & 0b01){
    // 1 or 3 selected
}
if (opt & 0b10){
    // 2 or 3 selected
}
```

My *binary literals* `0b01` &c. are a compiler extension. If your compiler doesn't support them, then use an alternative such as the less clear 1, 2, and 3 or standard hexadecimal constants such as `0x01` &c. which can flag to readers of your code that bit locations are important.

Comment: *use an alternative such as the less clear 1, 2, and 3.*  Personally, I like using hex constants such as `0x01`, `0x02`, and `0x03` in code like this.  The use of hexadecimal values is a flag that bit location may be important, especially if `0b...` binary literals aren't available.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, that has a lot of truth in it.

Comment: This helps a lot but how would I put both conditions for testing on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

You could us "else if" syntax as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int opt;

    printf("(1) Option 1");
    printf("\n(2) Option 2");
    printf("\n(3) Both\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf(" %d", &opt);

    if (opt == 3){
        printf("\nBoth");
    }
    else if (opt == 2){
        printf("\n2");
    }
    else{
        printf("\n1");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't one simply refactor `if (opt == 3)` outside of the other if-statements? How does this shorten the OP's switch statements, I'm curious...

Comment: Wouldn't this just make the code longer. Cause where you have printf("both"); all the code to be executed for opt 1 and opt 2 would be there and the else would execute just for that particular option